# Directory require all denied not working

Tags: linux, apache2, apache2.4

I created a virtual host and tried to forbid access to it by using the directory directive with `Require all denied`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test

    <Directory /var/www/test/>
        Require all denied
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

However, the users have still access to every page. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 4):

These directives won't do anything if they're in a VirtualHost not matched by the current request.

Your VirtualHost has no ServerName nor ServerAlias, which is the primary means of having a VirtualHost used for a request.

If you think configuration is being ignored, step is to verify that this VirtualHost is in use.  One simply way is to define a unique logfile for the virtual host.  Yours does not look unique.

```
apachectl -S will quickly summarize your virtual hosts.
```

Comment: Can you please tell what is wrong in the above config instead of giving a hint for answer?

Comment: Missing ServerName directive

Answer (score 1):

The `Require` must not be combined with the deprecated `Order`, `Allow`, `Deny` directives (since Apache 2.4).
Review all the configuration files and replace Order/Allow/Deny with `Require`, possibly combined using `RequireAll`, `RequireAny`, `RequireNone`.

Note that the configuration is not necesarrily located in the single file holding `<VirtualHost>`. You need to review all the server configuration files.
E.g. on Ubuntu this includes:

- all files in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`
- all files in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled`
- depending on `AllowOverride` setting you may need to review all the `.htaccess` files for any directories reachable from the web